# How to form a tree from data set with cyclic relations?

Tags: java, tree, cyclic-reference

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    public String name = "";
    public ArrayList<Foo> children = new ArrayList<Foo>();
}
```

Now, I have about two thousand of these 'Foo' objects stored in ArrayList, and they are related to each other as you can see from the snippet above. Now, these relations may be cyclic: A may have a child B, which may have child C, which may have child A. What I want to do is to print out a tree of these relations while ignoring the cyclic relations, like this:

```
ObjA
  ObjB
    ObjC
ObjD
  ObjB
    ObjA
```

How can I do this? It doesn't have to be fast or anything, this tree would be mainly for ensuring the results of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo` needs a `print` method that prints its contents and then calls the `print` method of the `Foo` it's pointing to.  `Print` takes a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) that contains all `Foo` objects that have been traversed.  If `next` is in `visited` then it's part of a cycle and you don't call its `print` method.

```
class Foo {
    Foo next;
    void print(HashSet<Foo> visited) {
        System.out.println("this Foo's ID or whatever it is you're printing");
        visited.add(this);
        if(next != null && !visited.contains(next)) {
            next.print(visited);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to pass in an `int` parameter that determines the level of indentation - if `indent` equals 4 then print 4 spaces before the `System.out.println`, and increment `indent` by 2 or 4 or whatever when you call `print` on `next`.

Comment: Thanks! It was so simple, I can't understand how I didn't see it myself. :)